# How to find out what your set working hours are in FogBugz?

Tags: fogbugz

I keep getting a message at work when I use FogBugz earily in the morning that says that I'm outside of working hours.  How do I find out what these working hours are set to?

Answer (score 0):

Click on "My settings" on top right hand side of the screen after logging into fogbugz. "Working Schedule" is at the bottom of the list.